# Laravel user management

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

In Laravel we can manage Users and Permissions easly but i've a problem with my application.

In my application a User is attached to One or Many department.

But a User can have different Role/Permission between departments. That is the problem. In the department One he can have a Admin Role and in the department Two he can only have a User Role. When the User switch between department i would like that his Role can be update.

How i can manage this in Laravel and Eloquent ?

Thank you for your help.

Jeffrey

Comment: What does your current model/code look like?

Comment: @TedGoas I use Entrust to manage Users Roles Permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing any of your code, I am forced to be fairly generic here. But here is the basic concept.

## Architecture

Assuming you have tables like `departments`, `users`, `roles`, and `permissions` already, all you would need next is define a joining table. Something like this:

- `department_role_user`

  - `department_id` // for this department
  - `role_id` // this role is assigned to
  - `user_id` // this user

## Authorization

Define something like a `hasPermissionTo()` method on your User model.

#### Definition

```
class User
{
    public function hasPermissionTo($action, $department)
    {
        // first get permission
        $permission = Permission::where('action', $action)->first();

        // get all roles which have this permission
        $roles = $permission->roles;

        return DB::table('department_role_user')
            ->where('user_id', $this->id) // current user
            ->where('department_id', $department->id) // the dept
            ->whereIn('role_id', $roles->pluck('id')) // any of the roles
            ->exists();
    }
}
```

#### Usage

And use it like so.

```
if ($user->hasPermissionTo('do-something', $someDept)) {
    // allow action
} else {
    // no way
}
```

This should also work nicely with Laravel's [Gates](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#gates) and [Policies](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#creating-policies). Just use your new `hasPermissionTo()` method inside your gate/policy definitions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try this solution.